# Sollte der Plural von Status im Schriftlichen vermieden werden?

Tags: style, grammatical-number

Es geht um eine Übersicht unfertiger Projekte, die einen Indikator besitzen, der anzeigt in welchem Status sich das Projekt befindet. Wenn ich in der Programmbeschreibung sagen möchte:

> In diesem Bereich werden die Projektstatus dargestellt.

sollte ich dann lieber ausweichen auf:

> In diesem Bereich werden die Projektzustände dargestellt.

**Edit:** Auf Anraten von Hendrik Vogt habe ich meine Frage ein klein wenig erweitert, um sie hoffentlich verständlicher zu machen.

Comment: Ich finde es im mündlichen ähnlich schwierig, "Statús" zu sagen. Man wird unweigerlich seltsam angeguckt.

Comment: mündlich würde ich immer auf "Statusse" zurückgreifen. Ist nicht ganz richtig, aber auch nicht ganz falsch und wird leichter verstanden. Geschrieben sieht es aber komisch aus, daher ist "Zustände" sicher 100-mal besser.

Comment: Die Antwort von OregonGhost führt mich auf die Frage: Warum möchtest Du hier überhaupt den Plural verwenden?

Comment: @Hendrik: Am liebsten würde ich die Dokumentation gar nicht schreiben :-) Was ich hier ausdrücken möchte ist folgendes: Es geht um eine Übersicht unfertiger Projekte, die einen Indikator haben, der anzeigt in welchem Status sich das Projekt befindet.

Comment: Je nach Kontext kann man auch *Verlauf* oder *Entwicklung* als Synonyme nehmen. Ein Grafik kann zum Beispiel den zeitlichen Verlauf des Projektes darstellen (Den Fortschritt allgemein, aber auch Anzahl (behobenener) Fehler). Für Entwicklung gilt das auch, z.B.: Entwicklung der Kosten im Vergleich zum Aufwand.

Comment: Wieso sollte man eine richtige Ausdrucksweise vermeiden wollen?

Comment: @user: Was _richtig_ ist, ist noch lange nicht _gut_. Wenn man eine Dokumentation schreibt, sollte man sich so verständlich wie möglich ausdrücken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hier ein Vorschlag zur Umsetzung der Idee von OregonGhost, den Plural ganz zu vermeiden:

> In diesem Bereich wird für jedes Projekt der jeweilige Status dargestellt.

Ich denke, die Verwendung des Plurals von *Status* ist in den allermeisten Fällen unnötig oder (wie hier) vermeidbar.

Comment: Vielen Dank, ich habe mich jetzt für diese Variante entschieden. Ich wünschte ich könnte mehr als ein Häkchen verteilen :-)

Comment: `In diesem Bereich wird der Projektstatus dargestellt.` scheint mir ebenso richtig.

Comment: @user: Siehe den Kommentar von bjoernz zu seiner Frage: Es geht um mehrere Projekte.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Vom Elfmeterpunkt wird der Elfmeter geschossen. Der Status des Projekts kann generisch gelesen werden.

Comment: @user: Ja, _kann_. Aber dann ist die Formulierung nicht mehr so präzise und unmissverständlich: Es wird nicht mehr ausgedrückt, dass es mehrere Projekt gibt und dass wirklich für jedes der Status dargestellt wird.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Ich kenne ja das Programm nicht. Wenn sich das Feld in einer Art Tabelle befindet wäre das wohl offenkundig. "In diesen Bereich tragen Sie den Namen des Projekts ein." / "... für jedes Projekt den jeweiligen Namen ein."

Comment: @user: Ich sag mal so: bjoernz hat meine Antwort akzeptiert `:-)`

Answer (score 11):

Ich würde trotzdem guten Gewissens "Status" als Plural verwenden. Was (über die u-Deklination schlecht informierte) andere denken, spielt m. E. keine Rolle.

Optional - aber nicht ohne Vorbehalte, weil es sich nicht durchgesetzt hat - könnte man auch auf die Variante *"Statusse"* ausweichen. Sie wird analog zum Plural von *Sinus* gebildet. *Sinusse* wurde bereits in der 8. Duden-Auflage von 1905 aufgenommen; *Statusse* ist belegt in der 10. bis zur 13. Auflage (1929 bis 1947) sowie in Lutz-Mackensens-Wörterbüchern ([Quelle](http://faql.de/numerus.html)).

Comment: +1 für die Verwendung des korrekten Plurals.

Comment: +1 für Toleranz gegenüber halbkorrektem Plural. ;)

Comment: Gute Gelegenheit andere zu belehren. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Ich würde in der Tat auf die zweite Variante ausweichen. Das klingt imho einfach klarer und besser und das sollte das höchste Ziel sein.

Ein anderer Grund ist allerdings auch, dass meiner Erfahrung nach kaum jemand den Plural von Status korrekt verwendet. Recht häufig hört und liest man *Stati*, welches im Duden nicht einmal als ugs. erwähnt wird und damit komplett falsch ist. Damit dürfte die korrekte Verwendung nur zu Kopfschütteln und/oder unnötigen Diskussionen führen.

Comment: Hmm - _stati_ ist zwar grammatikalisch nicht vom Substantiv _status_ ableitbar, aber vom lateinischen Verb _stare_ (Partizip _status_, _stata_, _statum_, Plural _stati_, _statae_, _stata_). Das könnte man m.E. durchaus als "Zustände" übersetzen, aber ich bin kein Altphilologe und übernehme daher keine Gewähr dafür :)

Comment: Stimmt, die Verständlichkeit sollte im Vordergrund stehen.

Answer (score 6):

Was genau sind denn die Projektstatus in deinem Beispiel? Je nach Situation können andere Wörter vielleicht besser passen:

- Projektstatusinformation(en)
- Projektfortschritt(e)
- Projektmeldung(en) / (Projekt-) Fehlermeldung(en)
- Projektinformation(en)
- (Projekt-) Fehlerzustände
- (Projekt-) Fehler / Warnungen

möglicherweise ist auch der Plural unnötig und es kann ganz allgemein vom Projektstatus gesprochen werden.

Natürlich ist Projektzustände grundsätzlich eine Möglichkeit (generell würde ich auch Zustände statt Status sagen), jedoch könnte Projektzustände auch missverständlich sein, weil es sich vom Wort her eher auf den Zustand des Projekts insgesamt bezieht und nicht auf einzelne Meldungen oder ähnliches, für die ja das Wort Status oft herhalten muss.

Comment: +1 für die Empfehlung, den Plural ganz zu vermeiden.

Comment: Danke für deine Vorschläge. Ein Projekt besteht aus verschiedenen, sequentiellen Arbeitsschritten. Projektfortschritt ist also definitiv eine gute Alternative. Da wir aber in den Meetings bisher immer über den Status/Zustand eines Projektes gesprochen haben, werde ich wohl bei Zustände bleiben.

Comment: Schöne Vorschläge, die zeigen dass im Zweifelsfall eine Alternative keine Verlegenheitslösung zu sein braucht

Answer (score 4):

Ich benötige das Wort im Singular wie im Plural häufig, und habe das seltene Glück in einem Umfeld zu arbeiten, in dem die Kollegen mit vielen Spielarten der Sprache umgehen. Nur "falsch" scheint eher unbekannt zu sein. In der Folge habe ich mir meine zwischenzeitlich erworbenen straßentauglichen Kompromissvarianten und Umschreibungen anhand der alltäglichen Sprachvorbilder wieder abgewöhnt.

In der geprochenen Praxis ist der Unterschied zwischen Status (kurzes *u*, wie in Bus) und Statús (langes *u*, wie in Mus) deutlich vernehmbar, lediglich im schriftlichen bleibt dann im Deutschen als einziges Unterscheidungmerkmal der Artikel.

In einem Umfeld, in dem die ursprungssprachlich "richtige" Flektion von Wörtern, die ihren Weg ins Deutsche gefunden haben, nicht ganz so selbstverständlich ist, halte ich es für die geschickteste Lösung, eine sprachlich gute Analogie zu finden. OregonGhost hat am Beispiel *Projektstatus* gezeigt, daß das noch nicht einmal Verlegenheitslösungen zu sein brauchen.