# Wie ist die Aussprache des Plural von »Status«?

Tags: pronunciation, latin

Der Plural von *Status* wird ebenfalls *Status* geschrieben.
Eine Freundin erzählte mir einmal, dass bei der Aussprache des Plural das *u* als *ü* gesprochen wird, also *Statüs.*

Weder auf [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Status), noch auf [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Status) wird die Aussprache des Plural hörbar gemacht.
In der Lautschrift wird der Singular als [ˈstaːtʊs] (also mit [ʊ]) und der Plural als [ˈstaːtuːs] (also mit [uː]) dargestellt.
Aus der [Lautschrift-Erklärung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Deutsch/Lautschrift) erkenne ich leider nicht, wie dieses [u:] zu lesen ist.

**Meine Frage:**

Wie ist die Aussprache des Plural von *Status?*

Comment: Mit langem U (Statuuus).

Comment: Verwandt: [Warum haben Status und Modus einen unterschiedlichen Plural?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20388/2594), [Sollte der Plural von Status im Schriftlichen vermieden werden?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1514/2594)

Comment: Nach einer ähnlichen Diskussion bei uns auf der Arbeit haben wir uns auf "ˈʦuːˌʃtɛndə" geeinigt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Der Plural von Status wird mit langem "U" gesprochen und das ist auch die Bedeutung des Lautschrift-Symbols.

Das lange "U" hört sich dann an wie in "Mus". Etwas überspitzt formuliert, hört sich der Plural also nach "Statuuus" an.

Der Hintergrund hierfür ist die Herkunft aus dem Lateinischen. Für "status" gilt die so genannte U-Deklination und die ist im Nominativ Plural "status" mit langem U. Im Lateinischen wird das regelmäßig mit einem Querstrich über dem U dargestellt.

Comment: Vielleicht auch noch: das zu unterscheiden ist *sehr* hochsprachlich. (Praktisch nur Latinumsbesitzer halten das so?)

Comment: @LangLangC Guter Punkt, allerdings ist die Frage, ob das wirklich so ist. Einerseits gebe ich dir recht, weil man alle möglichen Varianten hört (meistens "Stati"). Andererseits wird in allen Quellen, auch den Links des OP, immer die korrekte Aussprache in Lautschrift angegeben. Nur, es wissen eben nur wenige.

Comment: Statusse! Wie Kaktusse!

Comment: @IQV: _Status_ gehört wahrscheinlich zu den Wörtern im Deutschen mit den meisten falschen Pluralformen. Neben _Statusse_ und _Stati_ ist hierfür auch ein _doppelter Plural_ (ironisch) beliebt: An den falschen Plural _Stati_ wird noch ein `s` drangehangen, so dass _Statis_ dabei rauskommt.